# Basic configuration for Wechat Js sdk

Tags: wechat

I have a subscription Official Account and I'm trying to use the basic js sdk test.

I'm using the sample code at the bottom of [this page](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT#Appendix_6:_Sample_Code).

It's supposed to work with very little manipulation, but I'm not sure what to do : for example I found in the code "YOUR-APPID-HERE", where I need to put my appID, but it's not specified anywhere. I could be missing other things like this, very basic setup I just don't know of. For example I don't know what to do with the .json files : `access_token.json` and `jsapi_ticket.json`.

Should I leave them blank of fill them with my info ? If so I know my OA token but I don't know how to find the ticket.
I'm getting {"errMsg":"config:invalid signature"} but I don't know how to apply most of [those fixes](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT#Appendix_5:_Common_Errors_and_Solutions).

What I've done so far:

- Declared my domain in the official account settings
- Uploaded the files on my server
- In `all.php`, I've replaced the arguments in `$jssdk = new JSSDK("YOUR-APP-ID", "YOUR-APP-SECRET");` with my appID and appSecret

I'm sorry my questions are a little fuzzy, I find it hard to go straight to the point and to give clear context at the same time. 
TL;DR is I'd need someone who's made the demo work to tell me what the basics are, I'm sure a lot of people would benefit from it.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

first let's try to clarify things out.

the access_token is provided by the wechatApi. It's the proof that you are logged in, with your official account. You can generate the access_token only with your appId and appSecret. Be aware that an access_token is valide only for 7200 secondes, so you need to have a function who renew this token before it expires.

[access token doc](http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/oa/basic-info/access-tokens#basic-info_access-tokens)

The jsapi_ticket gives you the access to Wechat JS API's endpoint.
You just need the access_token to generate it. It also need to be renewed quite often.

[js ticket doc](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT#Steps_for_Using_the_JS-SDK)

The *.json provided in your exemple are used as a storage for access_token and js_ticket.
You can store the token and the expiring time so you can always renew them before it expires.

Note that the link you posted is not an official documentation. Very useful for an overview but you need to double check with this [documentation](http://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki/5/963fc70b80dc75483a271298a76a8d59.html)

Also, wechat have now an official english [doc](http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/oa/getting-started/getting-started#getting-started_getting-started)

You can find more details for Oauth in [here](http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/web/login/login#login_login)